# appending array breaks program

Tags: python, arrays

I am writing a program to analyze some of our invoice data. Basically,I need to take an array containing each individual invoice we sent out over the past year & break it down into twelve arrays which contains the invoices for that month using the dateSeperate() function, so that monthly_transactions[0] returns Januaries transactions, monthly_transactions[1] returns Februaries & so forth.

I've managed to get it working so that dateSeperate returns monthly_transactions[0] as the january transactions. However, once all of the January data is entered, I attempt to append the monthly_transactions array using line 44. However, this just causes the program to break & become unrepsonsive. The code still executes & doesnt return an error, but Python becomes unresponsive & I have to force quite out of it.

I've been writing the the global array monthly_transactions. dateSeperate runs fine as long as I don't include the last else statement. If I do that, monthly_transactions[0] returns an array containing all of the january invoices. the issue arises in my last else statement, which when added, causes Python to freeze.

Can anyone help me shed any light on this?

I have written a program that defines all of the arrays I'm going to be using (yes I know global arrays aren't good. I'm a marketer trying to learn programming so any input you could give me on how to improve this would be much appreciated

```
import csv
line_items = []
monthly_transactions = []
accounts_seperated = []
```

Then I import all of my data and place it into the line_items array

```
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    global board_info 
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        item = []
        item.append(line["company id"])
        item.append(line["user id"])
        item.append(line["Amount"])
        item.append(line["Transaction Date"])
        item.append(line["FIrst Transaction"])
        line_items.append(item)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("ChurnTest.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)

#formats the transacation date data to make it more readable
def dateFormat():
    for i in range(len(line_items)):
        ddmmyyyy =(line_items[i][3])
        yyyymmdd = ddmmyyyy[6:] + "-"+ ddmmyyyy[:2] + "-"  + ddmmyyyy[3:5]
        line_items[i][3] = yyyymmdd

#Takes the line_items array and splits it into new array monthly_tranactions, where each value holds one month of data
def dateSeperate():
    for i in range(len(line_items)):
        #if there are no values in the monthly transactions, add the first line item
        if len(monthly_transactions) == 0:
            test = []
            test.append(line_items[i])
            monthly_transactions.append(test)
      # check to see if the line items year & month match a value already in the monthly_transaction array.
        else:
            for j in range(len(monthly_transactions)):
                line_year = line_items[i][3][:2]
                line_month = line_items[i][3][3:5]
                array_year = monthly_transactions[j][0][3][:2]
                array_month = monthly_transactions[j][0][3][3:5]
                #print(line_year, array_year, line_month, array_month)
                #If it does, add that line item to that month
                if line_year == array_year and line_month == array_month:
                    monthly_transactions[j].append(line_items[i])
                #Otherwise, create a new sub array for that month
                else:
                    monthly_transactions.append(line_items[i])
dateFormat()
dateSeperate()
print(monthly_transactions)
```

I would really, really appreciate any thoughts or feedback you guys could give me on this code.

Comment: You have nothing after your last `else:` so that would def not work

Comment: Ooops, I'm sorry. I had commented out the monthly_transactions.append(line_items[i]) after the else in order to try & figure out the problem, but the occurs then I do have the monthly_transactions.append(line_items[i]) statement after the last else. Thank you!

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, the code runs & then never returns anything, eventually becoming unresponsive

Comment: I don't see any return statements anywhere what is it supposed to return?

Comment: it doesn't return anything, it appends to the global array monthly_transactions. Is that bad?

Comment: @jasnonaz Can you provide any test data?

Comment: hmmm I can't share the data I've been using. I'll while up some sample data real quick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the OP, your `csv_dict_reader` function seems to do exactly what you want it to do, at least inasmuch as it appends data from its argument csv file to the top-level variable `line_items`. You said yourself that if you print out `line_items`, it shows the data that you want.

"But appending doesn't work." I take it you mean that appending the `line_items` to `monthly_transactions` isn't being done. The reason for that is that you didn't tell the program to do it! The appending that you're talking about is done as part of your `dateSeparate` function, however you still need to call the function.

I'm not sure exactly how you want to use your `dateFormat` and `dateSeparate` functions, but in order to use them, you need to include them in the main function somehow as calls, i.e. `dateFormat()` and `dateSeparate()`.

**EDIT:** You've created the potential for an endless loop in the last `else:` section, which extends `monthly_transactions` by 1 if the line/array year/month aren't equal. This is problematic because it's within the loop `for j in range(len(monthly_transactions)):`. This loop will never get to the end if the length of `monthly_transactions` is increased by 1 every time through.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm quite embarrassed, but I actually was calling both my dateFormat() & dateSeperate() functions. I really apologize for not including that before, its fixed in the main post now.

I've been writing the the global array monthly_transactions. dateSeperate runs fine as long as I don't include the last else statement. If I do that, monthly_transactions[0] returns an array containing all of the january invoices.

Comment: the issue arises in my last else statement, which when added causes Python to freeze.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I'll have to do some playing around with it to get it to work, but now at least I know what it is. I really, really appreciate your help.

Comment: I only wish my reputation was high enough for the site to let me upvote you.